# How to Break same Entity but different microservice domains

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices

I'm facing an case with my new microservice application.

I have an Entity as users (**An single table, but different roles**).

consider i have roles as **manager** and **reader**, And one more entity as 
**Book**.

Where the **manager** can assign **Books** to **readers**, And i have Microservices as **usermS**, **bookmS**.

When i want to get all the **readers** of **Book-A**, the API will go in to **bookmS**, but the user details are still with the **usermS**.

And also combined searches.

I'm more worried about the paginations and search for the **readers**, if the **readers** for a **Book** keeps increasing. Expected to get roles in future.

Comment: Doesn't sound like you are using DDD at all, why the tag?

Comment: Why are they microservices?

Comment: @Tseng, I'm not using DDD, But i would like to, the question is towards that.

Comment: @DevonBurriss, I'm not disclosing my actual application, I just have given an example scenario, so it won't sounds like application which needs to be in the scale of microservies, but actual application will be.

Comment: Well first. DDD is very specific to the problem domain. if you ask for A but want B which you don't tell, its not going to work. Where it may be right for A to do it in a way it may be wrong for B. Second you don't seem to have got any information on DDD since your question doesn't suggest anything on it. You are speaking of technical aspects (searches and pagination, database structures), but DDD isn't about technical aspects, its about the ubiquitious language and the specific problem and processes of that company its meant for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets first break down your problem:

start with the easy one:

When i want to get all the readers of Book-A, the API will go in to bookmS, **but the user details are still with the usermS.**

***your doubt here is how to show the user details from the bookms?***

there are two options :

1. When some user becomes a reader of your book save user name and email type of details in the reader object in bookms so that you could shown them , also listen to event of user detail change from userms so that you could update the readers.

good part here is that there is no dependency between userms and bookms.
bad part here is that you may need to update multiple reader entity when a user detail changes, small optimizations here is just update in the read  model.

2. get data first from bookms and then from userms .

good part : no event listening  , always consistent data.
bad part:  high dependency between bookms and userms and **And also combined searches.**

i would have gone with the first approach assuming user dosen't change the basic details on which you need to show data very frquently.

SECOND QUESTION:

***How to break the system using DDD?***

In this the first answer written given right direction to it. i just want to add a bit more.

You should consider manager and reader as entity in bookms and not as roles.
Reason from DDD and in general:
In General: A user could be managing a book and as well a reader .
DDD: Manager and Reader are notions which bookms (which actually should be named libraryms ) are part of the domain entity.

So your solutions would be:

userms :

user: person which has access to library and can apply for being a manager or a reader. there could be two roles - student , admin .

libraryms:
Manager Entity - users which are allowed to subscribe a book to readers.
ReaderEntity - any user which has taken a book subscriptions
BookEntity - represents a book registered in the library
BookSubscriptionEntity - its your choice, you could use the BookEntity but i would prefer this.

Now by separating the role as admin and manager as entity you achieved two things.

One is now a admin could be a reader as well and a student can be a manager as well.Also library microservice works according to DDD , easy to understand and some api like assign book to reader dosent need to check anyhthing from userms

Comment: I just want to remark that I didn't say managers and readers are roles in Library "bounded context" (BC), I said they are concepts in Library BC. A user with the reader role in IAM BC, will be a reader concept in Library BC. I say concept because it doesn't have to be an entity, it can be a value object. It will depend on how you model the domain and integration with the IAM BC. If the integration is synchronous REST API, managers and readers there will be value objects in the Library BC. It is analogous to the example in Vaughn Vernon red book, Implementing Domain Driven Design, pages 101-103

Comment: I really appreciated the answer. I have doubt, consider the email is been used for authentication by my userMs, the same email id should be duplicated in readerEntity and also in adminEntity, won't this be an problem of breaking normalization rules. And yes i can duplicate the data using event sourcing, but my concern is on the duplicate of same data across different entities.

Comment: @SureshVarman duplication of data is not a problem, you should always keep in check that you should not be doing lots and lots of stuff to make them eventual consistent. like in this case as email would not change much its ok to listen to that event and do update in the reader or manager

Comment: @choquero70 yes you are right manager and reader can be value objects in the bookms. i tried to gave one example where one can model them as Entity as well. Also i took clue from your answer on this.

Comment: @SureshVarman i wrote such large answer because in understand what kind of doubts we have when we started on this topic thanks.

Comment: @SureshVarman regarding your comment https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/101968503?noredirect=1 , I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

My ddd vision of your problem:

You have 2 bounded contexts, each one a microservice, and you have to integrate both of them translating concepts:

Identity and access management (IAM). Here you have the concepts of users and roles.

Library: Here you have the concepts of managers and readers, which are roles in IAM.

Regarding searches and information about readers, in the IAM bounded context you have the login name and the password for example, but IAM doesn't know about other details of a reader.

**UPDATE: About duplication of data**

In your comment https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/101968503?noredirect=1 , you mean duplicated data **across different entities inside the same BC** don't you? For example, having an email in Reader and Manager entities? You could do an abstract base entity with the common data, and both entities inherit from it. This is the approach in Vaughn Vernon's book.

The duplication of data just exists **across different BCs** if you go for an **async integration**. But there's no denormalization, each BC has its own database, and each database is normalizated.

Library BC (downstream) and IAM BC (upstream) are enventually consistent. Library BC will listen to IAM BC events, and will update its database. This means a delay that it is supposed you can live with. Regarding email, I wouldn't allow to modify it, since it is the login for the user, but that's just my opinion.

If you don't want to duplicate data across BCs, or you cannot live with the update delay in the downstream BC, you could go for a **sync integration**. So that everytime the Library BC needs data from the IAM BC, it calls an http rest api that IAM BC offers, and waits for the response.

Comment: Sounds good, just have one query lets say we have 3 BC for a different scenario in retail domain,

BC1: RetailerBilling Domain: Retailer has customer. 
BC2: Customer Support -> Here retailers are customer as per (UL)
BC3: IAM : How do we define role in BC3 which is being called by both BC1 and BC2 as customer in BC2  is retailer and just a customer (end user to who product is sold ) in BC1. 
Similarly Customer has different meaning in BC2 and BC1

So how do we define roles like User in BC3: is customer or retailer

Comment: @MrX if I understand well your problem, I would have BC1 = Billing , BC2 = Retailing , BC3 = IAM. BC1 owns the concept "Customer", BC2 owns the concept "Retailer". BC3 owns the concepts "User" and "Role". As a user is both a customer in BC1 and a retailer in BC2, it means that the user in BC3 has both roles associated (customer and retailer), not just one or the other, but both.

Comment: BC1 = Retailing , BC2 = Customer Support, BC3 = IAM.

BC1 owns concept : Retailer (Who sells product), Customer (To whom product is sold)

BC2 owns concept:  Customer , when customer-support reach out to customers (BC2) they are actually reaching out to retailers (from BC1).
So Customer (BC2) = Retailer (BC1)

IAM  owns concept User :
It can be retailer(BC1)/customer(BC2) = Both has same entity id. 
It can be customer(BC1) = His entity id is not equal to entity id of customer in BC2.
If there is retailer id:23, and customer with id 8.
In Customer support: customer id:23 also exist